# TypeError on read_csv, working in pandas .7, error in .8.0rc2, possible dependency error?

Tags: pandas

I am attempting to execute the following within python:

```
from pandas import *
tickdata = read_csv('/home/user/sourcefile.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates='TRUE')
```

The csv files has rows that look like:

```
2011/11/23 23:56:00.554389,1165.2500
2011/11/23 23:56:02.310943,1165.5000
2011/11/23 23:56:05.564009,1165.2500
```

On pandas .7, this executes fine.  On pandas .8.0rc2, I get the error below.  Because I have .7 and .8 installed on two different systems, I have not ruled out a dependency or python version difference.  Any ideas on how to get this to execute under .8 are appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 225, in read_csv
return _read(TextParser, filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 192, in _read
return parser.get_chunk()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 728, in get_chunk
index = self._agg_index(index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 846, in _agg_index
if try_parse_dates and self._should_parse_dates(self.index_col):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 874, in _should_parse_dates
return i in to_parse or name in to_parse
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the parser bug shown in the stack trace that you pasted. However, I'm wondering whether your date column is named "TRUE" or did you mean to just pass a boolean? I haven't dug through pandas history but I know that in 0.8 we are supporting much more complex date parsing behavior as part of the time series API so here we're interpreting the string value as a column name.

Comment: Doh! Yes, I did mean to pass a boolean, and I think your explanation accounts for the different behavior I saw between .7 and .8.  When I properly pass the boolean, it executes without error on .8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've reported the bug on GitHub (best place for bug reports):

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1544

Should have a resolution today or tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize at the time that I'd found a bug.  I just assumed there was an error somewhere in my code.  Chang got me straightened out.  Thanks!